# How do I manage a plot with two protagonists?

Tags: fiction, plot, characters, comics

I'm a beginner manga plot writer. On the first season of my story I have a protagonist A.

How can I manage the second season if I want as protagonists the protagonist A from the first season and a new character B who appears in the second season? How can I switch between narrating about A's actions and B's actions without these POV changes become tiring for the reader?

Comment: Hi Kotas and welcome to Writers. I think a little background would be of use here: switching between characters and POV is perfectly natural, even if late to the game. Can you please add a bit of info on how this is a problem in Manga?

Comment: I'm writing a light novel (if I can still call it "light novel" because it's about 100 pages :P) and then I will try to draw it as a Manga

Comment: OK, so as a story it's really not an issue. In fact it's very common to have more than one protagonist. Do you feel that it will become an issue once it is translated to manga?

Comment: Yes, I think so...
Actually the character A have never meet character B before and that could be a little annoying for the reader as he don't know almost anything about character B yet (not even his name :P)...

Comment: Is the problem switching between multiple first-person viewpoints, or simply between characters you're following closely? Is there actual narration? (I assume you're at a point where you're writing a script or outline.)

Comment: No. There is a narrator who isn't participating in the story (he will maybe appear on the third season :P ("What the f*ck?" moment for the reader)). On the first season I had more than 15 characters (+ the character B who is appearing on the last episode), but it wasn't a problem to switch the POV for a half chapter because almost every characters's actions are associated. The problem now is that some character's B actions are happening at the same time something important is happening in character A.

Comment: The answer is: "How can I manage the narrating of character's B actions without missing anything important about character A?" (Character A have never met Character B and reader doesn't know almost anything about Character B at the moment)

Comment: @Kostas. Hi. Character A has never met Character B, but do A and B know of each other, that the other exists? Does either know what the other has been or is up to, or has gone through? How much of the story does B know? I have a feeling that the way to handle the pov change will depend on the knowledge each of the characters, and the reader, has of the story at the time of the switch.

Comment: @KostasLifeboy Using narration makes it even easier to switch between characters. Both viewpoints don't literally have to run in synch, in real time, consider “Meanwhile, at the Hall of Justice.” The only reason you'll miss something is if you leave it out.

Comment: @Nicole Character A doesn't know anything about character B, but B knows.

Comment: Here is a Chapter's 2 summery of season 2: Character A is a 'corrupted' policeman who wants to take revenge for his family murder. After a lot of killings he is arrested. Character B is a hitman and will help Character A to escape. This is when Character A meets Character B for first time.

Comment: Sorry @KostasLifeboy, it's still not clear where the issue is. We want to keep down the number of comments on any question; could you please update your question with as much information (including details like you have given here) as possible to help make it clearer?

Comment: This is still a very unclear question. Placing on hold until it can be edited.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question with no one right answer, but if I were doing this, I might consider starting the second season with Character B and continuing up to the point where he meets Character A, and then backtracking to fill in on Character A.

The advantage is that Character B gets a strong solid uninterrupted block of narrative to establish himself.  The disadvantage is that it may turn off readers who are already invested in Character A.

One way to address the new disadvantage would be to wait until the moment they meet to do Character B's story (as a flashback).  Conversely, you could do Character B's story first, but add some foreshadowing of the importance he will have to Character A (i.e. have them visit the same locations, or pass each other on the street, etc.)